# Uncaught ReferenceError: myPrompt is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

me aparece este error, cuando hago click en el botón, no me aparece nada y me figura en la consola esto. No entiendo por qué. Mi idea es poder hacer un botón que diga "clickeame" y que en el prompt aparezca la opción de escribir un nombre y que en un párrafo abajo aparezca una pregunta con el nombre puesto en el prompt. No entiendo si es un error de sintaxis o hay algo mal en la asignación de la variable

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pruebas</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
  function myPrompt(){
    var persona_ = prompt("Por favor escribí tu nombre");

    if (persona_ != "") {
      document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = "Hola " + persona_ " ¿Cómo estás?"; 
    }
  }

</script>

</head>  

<body>

<button onclick="myPrompt()">Clickeame</button> <p id="nombre"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es un error tipográfico, te falta un `+` después de `persona_` en el innerHTML.  Perdona mis lios (si es que has seguido todos los cambios que he hecho). Cuando lo tengas solucionado puedes borrar la pregunta, pues las que tan solo son errores tipográficos no cuentan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un error tipográfico, tan solo debes cambiar esto:

```
document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = "Hola " + persona_ " ¿Cómo estás?";
```

por esto (te faltaba un signo `+` despues de **persona_**)

```
document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = "Hola " + persona_ + " ¿Cómo estás?";
```

Aquí te dejo un snippet con los cambios funcionando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

     <head>
       <title>Pruebas</title>

       <script type="text/javascript">
         function myPrompt() {
           var persona_ = prompt("Por favor escribí tu nombre");

           if (persona_ != "") {
             document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = "Hola " + persona_ + "  ¿Cómo estás?";
           }
         }
       </script>

     </head>

     <body>

       <button onclick="myPrompt()">Clickeame</button>
       <p id="nombre"></p>

     </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: Uh genial, muchísimas gracias. Recién arranco con esto y tengo esos errores tipográficos q no identifico nunca. Gracias!!! Me anduvo perfecto.